# Need to create an object of ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, synchronization

I want to create an object of ExecutorService without using

newSingleThreadExecutor(),

Executors.newFixedThreadPool()

and,

Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()

How to do it?This is first time I am going to use ExecutorService, googled a lot to find how it is instantiated with out defining any "number of threads" but failed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need the ExecutorService?

Comment: [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool())?

Answer (score 3):

Majority of factory methods within `java.util.concurrent.Executors` return either instance of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or its child [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). And if you check javadoc for [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), then you'll see that these are well-known implementations.

To avoid a call of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` you can if you take a look on sources code of [java.util.concurrent.Executors](http://massapi.com/source/jdk1.6.0_17/src/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java.html):

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                              60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                              new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well why you do not want to use the factory methods?

You can easily create objects on your own if you create a Executor Object like this factory method is (already) doing:

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                  60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}
```